# Android:How to add data to the ListView while downloading from the web

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, adapter

I am Downloading some data from web and displaying them into a list.

Now i want to add the item to the list when its downloaded means if whole data has 10 item if one is downloaded i want that data to add in the ListView so that list will become more attractive.

I am using AsyncTask to download the data and in post background i am binding collected data into the list using custom adapter.

Comment: Have the asynctask publish each item as a progress, like `publishProgress(myNewItem)`, and in the `onProgressUpdate`, add said item to your listAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using [Loaders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/loaders.html).  You will probably want to include the [compatibility library](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) in order to use that API and still support pre-3.0 devices.

Comment: i will check this out.But i want to use my existing code.Any idea of doing that with asynctask

Answer (score 0):

Use this approach it will help you to do so.

Load your asyntask by

```
new MyAsynTaskname().execute(myarguments);
```

After that, make your Asyntask something like

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Handle your current downloading process in "onProgressUpdate" task.

Follow this [Android Asyntask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: my question is how to add item one by one. add one when one is downloaded second when second is downloaded.

Comment: Do you want me to give you the code? Just set the time inteval by using the handler. Follow this link [link](http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/01/using-handler-in-android.html).